# Obtain type of component's children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using `react-router` in my app, and it looks something like this:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Root}>
        <Route path="about" component={Child1} />
        <Route path="about" component={Child2} />
        // and so on...
    </Route>
</Router>
```

I would like to know the type of the child which is passed down to `Root` each time there is a change. Something like this:

```
if(typeof this.props.children === Child1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The children may be of varying types, so if there may be multiple children, you need to check `this.props.children[0]` and such, not `children` as a whole. (As you point out in a comment below: `props.children` is apparently the single child if there is a single child; otherwise, it's an *array-like* list of children.)

I have no idea if it's documented, but the entry in `children` appears to have a `type` property referring to the constructor for the element:

```js
class Child1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Child1</div>;
  }
}
class Child2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Child2</div>;
  }
}
const Main = props => {
  const children = "length" in props.children
    ? Array.from(props.children)
    : [props.children];
  console.log(`Children in '${props.title}':`);
  children.forEach((child, index) => {
    console.log(`* ${index}: ${child.type.name}`);
  });
  return (
    <div style={{paddingLeft: "6px"}}>
      {props.title}
      <div>
      {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Main title="Two children">
      <Child1 />
      <Child2 />
    </Main>
    <Main title="One child of type 1">
      <Child1 />
    </Main>
    <Main title="One child of type 2">
      <Child2 />
    </Main>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If the component only contains a single child, `this.props.children` returns the only child instead of a single-element array.

Comment: @cynicaldevil: **Wow**, I didn't know that. That's...crazy. Anyway, hopefully the `type` thing I mentioned in the edit helps.